# Regression with Keras or what model should i use?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

I am lost and have no idea if CNN is what I need.

I have a small .csv dataset of soccer statistics (~3,5k rows and 28 columns).

p.E.:

```
players; min;  goal; foul; ... tackle
14;      1004; 0;    12;   ... 3
14;      977;  1;    8;    ... 0
...
```

Each row represents a team from a soccer match and their performance (goals, fouls, minutes played, etc..); I want to get a numerical value ( preferable -50,00 to 50,00) representing the performance of the team.

```
poits;
45,3;
-23,01
...
```

After talking to a friend he suggested I use a CNN Regression Model so I looked into Keras for python and tried a model, but with no success and a `"val_loss did not improve from 0.00000"`.

The code for my Model, maybe I am just doing it wrong:

```
>>> model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal',input_dim = train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
>>> model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
>>> model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
>>> model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))
>>> model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

>>> checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, mode ='auto')
>>> callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
>>> history = model.fit(train, target, epochs=500, batch_size=32, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Is my thought process wrong that this `model.fit` should fill my target with my wanted values?

Comment: 1) this is not a CNN 2) you don't need a CNN 3) remove the `kernel_initializer='normal'` argument from all your layers (i.e leave the default one) and try again. You may also remove the redundant `metrics` (you don't need it, since it is the same with your loss).

Comment: In any case you can try a LSTM

Comment: How are you encoding your data?

Comment: @desertnaut thank you, now I get an accuracy of 0.00007, but my target array is still [0., ..., 0.] - am I missing something or am I completely wrong with my a NN?

Comment: @erip do you mean how the csv is encoded? UTF-8

Comment: You cannot have any "accuracy" in a regression problem (it is defined for classification only) - do you mean MAE?

Comment: @CeliusStingher would a LSTM yield the outcome I am trying to get? (List of decimal values)

Comment: I don't mean the file encoding. In order to feed data to your model, you generally need to ensure it's properly encoded in some fixed length representation. Neural nets understand numbers, not rows in a CSV.

Comment: As said, we don't use the term "accuracy" in regression; other than that, the MAE is indeed your performance indicator (the lower the better).

Comment: @erip tbh I have no idea but I suppose Integer Encoding as I am using only integers.

Comment: Please read closely the already existing comments; your performance metric is your `val_loss` (here MAE).

Comment: @desertnaut I am not sure we are talking about the same thing. I meant if predict() is the performance (points) as in how the team (row) performed.

Comment: Your `prediction` variable will contain what you are trying to predict; if you call this performance, then yes. Please keep in mind that these are very elementary questions, and SO is *not* a tutorial service.